# Is there any way to send a http request to all instances in a AWS ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, varnish, autoscaling, amazon-elb

I will make an array of Varnish servers using Amazon Auto Scaling. With that, I'll have to send a purge request to all servers that are as healthy on the load balancer.

It is possible? What is the easiest way to do? Should I use API?

Answer (score 4):

That's fairly straightforward using awscli / API.

1. Get healthy instance IDs from ELB using `aws elb describe-instance-health`. Lots of examples here: [AWS CLI - elb describe-instance-health](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/describe-instance-health.html)
2. Get IP addresses of your healthy instances by using `aws ec2 describe-instances`. Docs here: [AWS CLI - ec2 describe-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)
3. Once you have IP addresses just do what is needed on your EC2 instances (make sure your security groups are set up properly).