# API call to all instances behind AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

I am trying to hit an endpoint on multiple instances running the same application on Elastic Beanstalk (so behind a load balancer).

What is the best way to call an endpoint on all the instances - and be certain that it has been received?

I have thought through SNS (which is a slight overkill for our needs). I have looked into ELB API to find instances, then finding the public dns for the instances and call the endpoint - but cannot find any examples of this.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What is the use of ELB when you want reach specific instance?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445647/is-there-any-way-to-send-a-http-request-to-all-instances-in-a-aws-elb and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701738/send-a-request-to-all-machines-behind-an-aws-elb

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. This is how we ended up doing this. We had the calling instance be an incoming security group for the target instances' security group, and used AWS describeinstances to find the instances and call their private APIs

Answer (score 1):

If your EC2 instances that are behind the load balancer have Public IP addresses, then go to their public address. If your EC2 instances have Private IP addresses then go to the private address via your VPN or Bastion Host.

Amazon's Load Balancers (CLB / ALB / NLB) do not support what you want to do.

Note: Your EC2 instances should only have private IP addresses and be located in private subnets so that your EC2 instances can only be accessed by third parties using the load balancer. Otherwise bad actors will just go around your load balancer and hammer directly on your EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the reasoning behind it, you could...

Build your API such as it could let any of the instances proxy your call to the others.

For example if you hit elb-domain.xyz/myendpoint, then the instance serving the request could query available instances under its load balancer using AWS API. Then your API function would proxy the request to all others instances as needed. You need to protect against a dominio effect/infinite loop by flagging the second request not to proxy further.

You can either do that asynchronously or by waiting for all instances to return successfully before returning to the client.

The advantages of such method

- Can keep your instances in the private VPC without a public IP.
- Your clients wouldn't need to know instances details.
- It can adapt to autoscaling (you must handle newly scaled instances that are still not ready to process your request)
- An IAM role that allows the instance to complete this task without they need to have access/secret keys stored elsewhere.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the AWS API that you mentioned in the answer. Is there such an API, if so can you please link to the documentation